# Short jquery exit popup script needs ammending somehow

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

Below is a script for an exit popup that I found on the internet.

This script works perfectly. It changes the page at the same time as the exit popup shows with Leave/Stay on page buttons.

However - I'm looking to make it work two times in a row, for example, you are on index.php.

You press exit and the current page AJAX loads and overlays page_exit.php (still technically on index.php)

User decides to stay on the page and read the new overlayed div.

After you try to close the page again, but this time it reloads the div with page_exit_2.php.

At the moment it will just keep trying to load page_exit.php and I am unsure how to tell it to load the page_exit_2.php after the first attempt to exit.

Thank you.

```
var ExitPopURL = 'page_exit.php'; //This is the URL where your 'exit page' is located.

var AlertBox = "*****************************************************\n\nWait! Stop! Don't Go!\n\nBefore leaving, we have a special offer for you\n\nClick Sty On Page Now\n\n*****************************************************"; // This is what the alert() pop up verbage says.


window.onload = function(){
    // this is where we start our journey...
    createExitPop();
}// end function onunload

function getChildren(n, skipMe){
    var r = [];
    var elem = null;
    for ( ; n; n = n.nextSibling ) 
       if ( n.nodeType == 1 && n != skipMe)
          r.push( n );        
    return r;
};

function getSiblings(n) {
    return getChildren(n.parentNode.firstChild, n);
}


function ajaxGET(divId, page, effect) 
{ 
     var xmlHttp; 
     try 
    { 
         // Firefox, Opera 8.0+, Safari 
         xmlHttp=new XMLHttpRequest(); 
    } 
     catch(e)   
    { 
         // Internet Explorer 
         try 
         { 
              xmlHttp=new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP"); 
         } 
         catch(e)   
          { 
               try 
               { 
                    xmlHttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP"); 
               } 
               catch(e)   
             {      
                    alert("Your browser does not support AJAX!"); 
                  return false; 
             } 
         } 
     } 

    xmlHttp.onreadystatechange=function() 
     { 
         if(xmlHttp.readyState==4) 
          { 
               if(effect == 'collapse') { document.getElementById(divId).style.display='none'; } 
               else                     { document.getElementById(divId).innerHTML=xmlHttp.responseText; } 
         } 
    } 
     xmlHttp.open("GET",page,true); 
    xmlHttp.send(null); 
}

function createExitPop()
{
    var theBody = document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0]; 
    var newdiv = document.createElement('div');
    newdiv.setAttribute('id','ExitDiv');
    theBody.setAttribute('id','body');
    newdiv.setAttribute('style', 'width: 100%; height: 100%;');

        // put div on page
        theBody.appendChild(newdiv);

        //add exit pop to page (contents are from your exit.php(or whatever you named it) page)
        document.getElementById('ExitDiv').value = ajaxGET('ExitDiv', ExitPopURL);

    // style exit pop to resemble its own page
    document.getElementById('ExitDiv').style.display = "none"; 
    document.getElementById('ExitDiv').style.top = '0px'; 
    document.getElementById('ExitDiv').style.left = '0px'; 
    document.getElementById('ExitDiv').style.position = 'relative'; 
    //document.getElementById('ExitDiv').style.backgroundColor = '#FFFFFF';
    document.getElementById('ExitDiv').style.zIndex = 9999;

}// end createExitPop

isExit = true;

function ExitPop(isExit) {
        if(isExit != false) {
            isExit=false;
            isPop = true;

            var bodyTag = document.getElementById? document.getElementsByTagName("BODY")[0] : document.body;

            // add id="body" so that it can be referenced.
            bodyTag.setAttribute("id", "body");



            //replace body text with exit pop
            //bodyTag.innerHTML = document.getElementById('ExitDiv').innerHTML;
            document.getElementById('ExitDiv').style.display = "block"; 

            var oldContent = getSiblings(document.getElementById('ExitDiv'));
            for(i in oldContent ){
                 oldContent[i].style.display = "none";
            }

            return AlertBox;
        } // end if
    }// end function

window.onbeforeunload = function(){

        // Lay down an exit pop!!
        return ExitPop(isExit);

}// end function onunload
```

Comment: Yikes! Isn't this kind of nagging anti-social? If all websites worked liked this, we'd be making the web a very frustrating place indeed.

Comment: Well, the only way to see the 2nd exit page is to click 'Stay On Page' for the first one, and then decide to exit again.  You are right thought, personally I dont like them, but it's for a new project of mine :)

Comment: use session or a variable to store the status, if exit once then value set to 1 or true. do the exit page  page_exit.php ||  page_exit_2.php? but like halfer said personally doesn't like this approach at all

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I tried changing the variable after the first popup is sent. But it seems the javascript isn't read again after that. I don't know javascript very well so where would I add the code in the above script? Your help is greatly appreciated. I also do not like these but it's for a project that only a few people will see.

Comment: I tried changing ExitPopURL at window.onbeforeunload = function(){ but it didn't work. It seems the function is only being called once. Any idea?